# How to extract date ranges for the last 3 occurrences of event 'y' given dataframe df?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with the following data, how can I use python and pandas to extract the last 3 occurrences of a given event 'Y'?

```
         Date Customer Event
0    1/1/2013      Tom     N
1    1/3/2013      Tom     Y
2    1/5/2013    Harry     Y
3    1/7/2013     Dick     N
4    1/9/2013      Tom     Y
5   1/11/2013      Tom     Y
6   1/13/2013    Harry     N
7   1/15/2013     Dick     Y
8   1/17/2013      Tom     Y
9   1/19/2013      Tom     N
10  1/21/2013    Harry     Y
11  1/23/2013     Dick     Y
12  1/25/2013      Tom     N
14  1/29/2013    Harry     Y
15  1/31/2013     Dick     N
16   2/2/2013      Tom     Y
17   2/4/2013      Tom     Y
18   2/6/2013    Harry     N
19   2/8/2013     Dick     Y
20  2/10/2013      Tom     Y
21  2/12/2013      Tom     N
```

Expected results should be

```
        Start           End
Tom     2/2/2013    2/10/2013
Harry   1/5/2013    1/29/2013
Dick    1/15/2013   2/8/2013
```

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: what are start and end? they don't seem to first and last occurrences.

Comment: Sorry that should have been - Given a dataframe with the following data, how can I use python and pandas to extract the *date range* for  last 3 occurrences of a given event 'Y', *per customer* ?

Answer (score 3):

If the DataFrame is named df, you could try:

```
    df[df['Event'] == 'Y'][-3:]
```

Comment: You can also use `.tail(3)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Anupan, thanks for you tip. Your suggestion returns the last 3 events where Event ==       'Y' regardless of customer

```
df[df['Event'] == 'Y'][-3:]
Out[133]: 
    Date         Customer Event
17  2/4/2013     Tom      Y
19  2/8/2013     Dick     Y
20  2/10/2013    Tom      Y
```

I needed the date range for the last 3 'Y' events per customer. I'm sure there is a more efficient way but the following works.

```
df.ix[df.Customer == 'Tom'].ix[df.ix[df.Customer == 'Tom'].Event == 'Y'][-3:]
Out[134]: 
     Date          Customer Event
16   2/2/2013      Tom      Y
17   2/4/2013      Tom      Y
20  2/10/2013      Tom      Y


df.ix[df.Customer == 'Dick'].ix[df.ix[df.Customer == 'Dick'].Event == 'Y'][-3:]
Out[135]: 
     Date         Customer Event
7    1/15/2013    Dick     Y
11   1/23/2013    Dick     Y
19   2/8/2013     Dick     Y
```

etc, etc

Thanks